# flask-sqlalchemy: how to make a selectable button to select the users according to his role id?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

This is based on the [flask-admin example](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/6a06ae064cac3020c10a41ea41b946c386303a9b/examples/auth/app.py).

I want to build the selectable drop button to select the users in the database according to  the role id instead of all users.

For example: Say **superusers(role id=2)**, how can I make a selectable button that restrict only the users are **superusers** can be selected (in my `class Project`)?

```
roles_users = db.Table(
   'roles_users',
   db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
   db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)


class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                         backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
     email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.email

class Project(db.Model):
      *some code here make the selectable button to select users that are superusers*
```

**The role table:**

[image]

**The role-user table:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` model defines a many-to-many relationship with the `Role` model.  You can use this relationship to query users by role id.

```
users = User.query.join(User.roles).filter(Role.id == 123).all()
```

Alternatively, you can query the `Role` first and then use the `users` attribute to access the users for the role.

```
role = Role.query.get(123)
users = role.users
```

For more information, see the SQLAlchemy documentation:

- [Many-to-many relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)
- [`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join)

Comment: @ augurar: Thanks for the reply, do you mean adding  `users = User.query.join(User.roles).filter(Role.id == 123).all()` in my `class Project` here? I tried the above but an error occured : `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|User|user, expression 'Project' failed to locate a name ("name 'Project' is not defined")`.

Comment: The code snippets just show how to make the queries.  How you use them is up to you.  If you want help debugging an error you should create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post a new question.

Comment: @ augurar: Thanks for your kind answer, what if I want to query the user with `Role.id == 123` and `Team.id == current_user.team_id`?

Comment: If you want to filter on two conditions, you can add another [`Query.filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) call when building the query.  Alternatively, you may want to use the [`Query.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) method.

Comment: More generally, learn how SQLAlchemy works by reading the documentation, and then use that knowledge to construct your queries.  That's going to be much more efficient in the long term than trying to get StackOverflow users to write each query for you.

Comment: Thanks, I used `User.query.join(User.roles).join(User.teams).filter(Role.id == 4).filter(Team.id == current_user.teams.id)` to achieve this.